# Dense network in keras input issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am having quite a weird issue in which I am giving proper input to the keras model but getting an input tensor not found error like this:-

> "ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
>   Tensor("input_12:0", shape=(?, 3212, 1), dtype=float32) at layer
>   "input_12". The following previous layers were accessed without issue:
>   []"

Here is how I am making the model, there are no import errors. I also tried expanding last dimension of data and tried giving input in shape (3212,1) but it didn't work also, please tell me what I am doing wrong, any help will be much appreciated.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feats,y,test_size=0.1,random_state=42,shuffle=True)

print(X_train.shape)   # prints (24723, 3212)

x = Input(shape=(3212,))

x=Dense(64)(x)
x=LeakyReLU()(x)
x=Dropout(0.4)(x)

x=Dense(128)(x)
x=LeakyReLU()(x)
x=Dropout(0.4)(x)

x=Dense(256, name='dense3')(x)
x=LeakyReLU()(x)
x=Dropout(0.4)(x)

x=Dense(512, name='dense23')(x)
x=LeakyReLU()(x)
x=Dropout(0.4)(x)

x=Dense(1024, name='dense33')(x)
x=LeakyReLU()(x)
x=Dropout(0.4)(x)

x=Dense(2048, name='dense43')(x)
x=LeakyReLU()(x)

output=Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(x, output)

adam=Adam(lr=0.0001)

model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

model.summary()

from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

es=keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=2, verbose=0, mode='auto',baseline=None, restore_best_weights=True)

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                epochs=10,
                batch_size=64,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                callbacks=[es])
model.save('DNN_model.h5')
```

Comment: You lost the initial x variable that contains the Input, you should keep it as it is the one you have to pass as input to Model.

Comment: Can't believe I did something that stupid, thanks